# Oracle Apex : Get Selected list value and use the value in another region

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex

Dears ,

I Have a selected list that contain values dynamiclly from the database ,
I am trying to build a Region Classic Report (Base on Function ) Using the selected value.
The source code of this region based on PL/SQL Function Body returning SQL Query as below :

```
DECLARE
   V_SELECT    VARCHAR2 (4000);
   V_SELECT2   VARCHAR2 (4000);
   V_DESC      VARCHAR2 (1000);
BEGIN
   IF :P1224144_PRE_SEL IS NULL
   THEN
      V_SELECT :=
            'SELECT '
         || LTRIM (GML.GML_GET_COLUMNS ('RI'), ',')
         || ' FROM GML.GML_SCENARIOS ';
      RETURN V_SELECT;
   ELSE
      V_SELECT2 :=
            'SELECT '
         || LTRIM (GML.GML_GET_COLUMNS (:P1224144_PRE_SEL), ',')
         || ' FROM GML.GML_SCENARIOS ';
      RETURN V_SELECT2;
   END IF;
END;
```

My problem is that i cant get the selected value from the list always return null and the code will execute the first select (V_SELECT ) only .
I put the Page Action on Selection of the List as Redirect and Set Value .
[Correct Result when select null value Or 'RI'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lh8Vv.png)

[No data found  is the result when select Not null value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkSCm.png)

Please Advice
Best Regards
Yousef Farraj

Comment: Have you tried selecting RI

Comment: Yes its giving the same result as null but anything else return no data found

Comment: Inspect the data in gml_scenarios

Comment: Everything is ok , i tried to change the 'RI' on the null condition to 'P' and 'LI' and its getting the data correct ,so the problem is i cannot get the selected list value its always execute the null select (V_SELECT )

Comment: Just print and debug the value of :P1224144_PRE_SEL to find the issue

Answer (score 0):

On the *Dynamic Actions* section, under action *Execute PL/SQL Code*, select all the items to submit in *Items to Submit* attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Apex reports regions (Classic and IR) have a property named **Page Items to Submit** in the **source** section, where you must include all page elements that you can change and its values are required when your query is executed. [image]